# How to count the selected checboxes with VueJS

Tags: vuejs2

i am new to VueJS and i am trying to make a dropdown list where it contains a few checkboxes with a button to select them all and an event click on each box to bind the click, and finaly i want to count the checked boxes in a `<p>{{selected}}</p>` tag.

```
<p>{{selected}}</p>

<div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body" v-for="(data, value) in filteredList">
    <label><input class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox" v-model="allChecked" :value="data.id" v-on:click="select(data, value)">{{data.name}}</label>
</div>

<div class="uk-inline">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="sAll" class="switchButton uk-button uk-button-default" value="Отметить все" v-model="checkAll">
    </label>
</div>

var menu = new Vue(
    {
        el: "#main_menu",
        data: function () {

            return {
                allChecked: [],
                selectedList: [],
                selected: 0,
                selections: [{id:1, name:"first"},{id:2, name:"second"},{id:3, name:"third"}]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            select: function(data, id){
                console.log(this.selectedList);
                if(this.selectedList.includes(data.name)){
                    this.selectedList.splice(id);
                } else {
                    this.selectedList.push(data.name);
                }
                this.selected = this.selectedList.length;
            }
        },
        computed: {
            checkAll: {
                get: function(){
                    return this.selections ? this.allChecked.length == this.selections.length: false;
                },
                set: function(value){
                    var allChecked = [];
                    if(value){
                        this.selections.forEach(function(item){
                            allChecked.push(item.id);
                        });
                    }
                    this.allChecked = allChecked;
                    this.selectedList = allChecked;
                    this.selected = allChecked.length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think it will be easier for you to handle this with adding a property to your list items and then derive the other things.

`options: [{id:1, name:"", selected: BOOLEAN}]`

Once you do that then all of the other things you are needing are a function of working on that list instead of editing state on multiple variables.

- For each checkbox, set the value of the checkbox to the boolean value of the option
- On checkbox click call a function that is `toggleOption(id)`, create that method to handle the toggling for finding by id and toggling its selected state
- On selectAll, loop through the list of options and set all of them to selected of true, deselectAll is the opposite
- To get the list of selected, create a computed property that selects all the options that are selected

Comment: It sounds a perfect idea, i will give it a try, thank you for your interest :)

Comment: No problem.  Good luck.  Here is a good article on v-model that may help you on your journey https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/ and also https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model